# What is the equivalent of pstop on OSX?

Tags: process, osx

Is there an equivalent of [`pstop`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7mii/index.html) in OSX?

How is `pstop` different to `kill`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent of `pstop` in OS X?

Yes. Send [`SIGSTOP`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/signal.3.html) to the process you want temporarily stopped.

The most direct way to do that is `kill -STOP $pid`, but you can use any of the several other methods for sending a signal from the command line on OS X: `pkill`, `killall` or `/bin/kill`.

(The latter as opposed to the shell builtin, that being what you normally get when you issue a `kill` command on OS X. Say `help kill` to see the differences with respect to `man kill`.)

> How is `pstop` different to `kill`?

If by "`kill`" you mean the default action, `kill -TERM`, the difference is that the `STOP` signal just suspends the process, ready to be started again later. It's the same thing that happens to an interactive process when you hit <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> from a modern shell.

(That feature is part of a larger group of features called [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)) which was introduced in BSD Unix as part of the [C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell), then later cloned in the [Korn shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell), which in turn was forked to become the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shell. That is why <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> works in the default interactive shell in almost every Unix or Unix-like system: because POSIX.)

When you want to resume the process, send it `SIGCONT`.